# AngularJS: How to display an object value with two ng-repeats in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I want to do is create a table in which I will provide the content, the headings (thead) and the body of the table as well. The content will be a JSON object and the headings and body attributes will be arrays.

What I've done so far:

Data in Controller (MainCtrl)

```
$scope.people = [
    {
        "name": "Adam",
        "age": "21", 
        "town": "IL",
        "work": "Manager"
    },
    {
        "name": "Christina",
        "age": "25", 
        "town": "MS",
        "work": "Designer"
    },
    {
        "name": "Luke",
        "age": "22", 
        "town": "VA",
        "work": "Developer"
    }
]

$scope.heads = ["Name", "Age", "Work"]
$scope.attrs = ["name", "age", "work"]
```

I managed to show the headings but the problem is with `{{ person.attr }}`. I cannot access the properties.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="head in heads">{{ head }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td ng-repeat="attr in attrs"> {{ person.attr }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
Name        Age        Work
-----------------------------------
Adam        21         Manager
Christina   25         Designer
Luke        22         Developer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to access a key name 'attr' in the object person, which does not exist. you should be using `person[attr]`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people">
      <td ng-repeat="attr in attrs"> {{ person[attr] }} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That worked! How do I access data that is two and three level deep such as 

`
{
        "name": "Luke",
        "age": "22", 
        places: { "town": "VA" },
        "work": "Developer"
    }
`

Comment: person['places']['town'] is an example of how it sould be done.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop twice if `attr` is fixed.

What you can do is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people">
    <td> {{ person.name }} </td>
    <td> {{ person.age}} </td>
    <td> {{ person.work }} </td>
</tr>
```

OR (if `attr` is not fixed):

```
 <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
   <td ng-repeat="attr in attrs"> {{person[attr]}} </td>
</tr>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("appModule", []);

var appController = app.controller("AppController", AppController);

appController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function AppController($scope){

    $scope.people = [
    {
        "name": "Adam",
        "age": "21", 
        "town": "IL",
        "work": "Manager"
    },
    {
        "name": "Christina",
        "age": "25", 
        "town": "MS",
        "work": "Designer"
    },
    {
        "name": "Luke",
        "age": "22", 
        "town": "VA",
        "work": "Developer"
    }
];

$scope.heads = ["Name", "Age", "Work"];
$scope.attrs = ["name", "age", "work"];



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app = "appModule">
   <table ng-controller = "AppController">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="head in heads">{{ head }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td ng-repeat="attr in attrs"> {{ person[attr]}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="head in heads">{{ head }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td ng-repeat="attr in attrs"> {{ person[attr] }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When u call person.attr it will try to find attr on person object

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-repeat by this way `{{person[attr]}}`

Comment: people should be person

Answer (score 0):

1.
If you want to use `'.'` operator then you have to provide attributes of person to print like `person.name person.town`

2.
if you want to take features from attrs array them you can try this.

```
 <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td ng-repeat="attr in attrs"> {{ person[attr]}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody
```